# Scheduling Multiple SMS at Different Times

Tags: android, alarmmanager, scheduler

I want to schedule multiple SMS at different times, for which I have saved name, number and message in a database. 
I have calculated the time difference and passed it to the Alarm Manager. For single data, every thing is working fine. When I schedule two or more SMS, then only the last SMS gets send.

Whats the reason behind it and how can it be solved?

Comment: I have same issue. can you give sample code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use alarm manager... put your extra data (sms text, address) in intent as extra and schedule it